# How do I show a "results count" on my search results page?

Tags: theming, search

I'm using Search API along with Facet API to administer a search for my products. I'm also overriding the search with a view. I'm looking for some method of counting the search results and displaying this information. For example, at the top of the search results page I want text to be displayed that reads something like "Showing 1 - 16 of 39,352 Results". I've read somewhere that views is able to do this easily, the problem is that I'm using facets and I don't think the results count from views will work together with applied facets. Can someone give me a solution or at least an idea?

Answer (score 2):

In the view that I'm using to override my search results, I added "Global: Result summary" to the views Header and it seems to be working with the facets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a module for this - https://drupal.org/project/views_record_count
Provides same functionality you are looking for.

Some details from the module's project page:

> This module will add some additional functionality in views. You can see the record count in views header/footer if you have chosen pager. You will see record count option as well when you edit the view.
>   If you setup some overridden values in you display, it work with them also.
>   Default message region is footer. You can change it as well.

Answer (score 0):

By using the below code, you can do that, It will display like this ***Showing 1-10 of 130 results***. on your result page.

Put this code in the page.tpl or **views Header and set the input filter as PHP code** in your view.

> ```
> <?php
> global $pager_page_array, $pager_total_items, $pager_total;
> $my_view = views_get_current_view();
> $items_per_page = $my_view->pager['items_per_page'];
> if ($pager_total[0] == 1) {
>   echo t('Showing <b>!pager_total_items</b> results',
>     array('!pager_total_items' => $pager_total_items[0])
>   );
> } else {
>   $start = 1 + ($pager_page_array[0] * $items_per_page);
>   $end = (1 + $pager_page_array[0]) * $items_per_page;
>   if ($end > $pager_total_items[0]) $end = $pager_total_items[0];
>   echo t('Showing !start-!end of <b>!pager_total_items</b> results',
>     array('!start' => $start, '!end' => $end, '!pager_total_items' => $pager_total_items[0])
>   );
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I put the code in the views Header and am getting the following error: "Notice: Undefined property: view::$pager in eval() (line 4 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code)."

Comment: Never mind. I added "Global: Result summary" to the views header and it seems to be working with the facets. Thanks.

Comment: @user22939, I was writing the same in my answer, but I got your comment before my posting so I have to skip my answer.

Comment: @user22939 then add your answer, it will help the future visitors.